# JQuery: How to add a CSS class to a HTML button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I have some CCS defined as following:

```
.FW_Buttons {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px; 
    background-color: #123456;
}
```

and I want to add it to a button defined like this:

```
<div id="but_begin"><button type="button" id="but2_begin">Go</button></div>
```

using JQuery (in document-ready):

```
$("#but2_begin").css("FW_Buttons");
```

but the css is not applied on the button. I have checked with FireBug: it is not there. No error is triggered when using a breakpoint.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#but2_begin").addClass("FW_Buttons");`

You want to use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) not [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BHBBA/)

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#but2_begin").addClass("FW_Buttons");
```

Answer (score 4):

.css is used to set/get css elements, in order to set a class you can use .addClass()

```
$("#but2_begin").addClass("FW_Buttons");
```

Make sure to take a look at other methods to deal with css classes, they may be usefull for you in the future:

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)